# Python: compile, rename & move

Tags: python

OK, so I have a project in Python. I made a batch file to compile all **.py** files. 
After the compilation I want to:

- delete all **.py** files (i don't need them anymore after compilation);
- find all **.pyc** files and rename them (ex: **game.cpython-36.pyc** should be renamed to **game.pyc**...so i just want to remove the **".cpython-36"** part from all **.pyc** files name) and after that move them one level (folder) up (where the **.py** files was initial);
- find all **pycache** folders that were created after compilation and that now should be empty (because we already moved .pyc files in the above step) and delete them.

I've already compiled the .py files (`python -m compileall -f C:\Pejo\`) but how exactly can I do the rest of the tasks?

I think that it should be something like this:

```
for /R C:\Pejo\ %%G in (*.py *.pyc) do (...)
```

but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-delete all .py files (i don't need them anymore after compilation);

> ```
> import os
> import shutils
>
> for file in os.listdir('path-to-files'):
>     if file.endswith('.py'):
>         os.remove(os.path.join('path-to-file', file)
> ```

find all .pyc files and rename them (ex: game.cpython-36.pyc should be renamed to game.pyc...

> ```
> for file in os.listdir('path-to-files'):
>     if file.endswith('.pyc'):
>         newName = file.split(".")[0] +'.' + file.split(".")[-1]
>         os.rename(os.path.join('path-to-file', file),os.path.join('path-to-file', newName)
>         shutils.move(os.path.join('path-to-file', newName),os.path.join('../', 'path_to_file'))
> ```

find all pycache folders that were created after compilation

> ```
> for folders in os.listdir('path-to-folders'):
>     if folders.startswith('pycache'):
>         os.rmdir(os.path.join('path-to-file', folder)
> ```